# Unable to get touch on my UIImageView - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I need to make my every single UIImageView to be single tapped.

I have a viewController, on this view controller there is a view which i push another views on this view with containment.

I am trying to create gallery ,

What might I be doing wrong?

This is my code;

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openPhotoDetail)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

}
return self;
}

-(void)openPhotoDetail
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SideMenu" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

PhotoDetailViewController *photoDetailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"photoDetailViewController"];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate.window.rootViewController.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController pushViewController:photoDetailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially a UIImageView has user interaction disabled. Enalbe the user interaction of your UIImageView and it should work.

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Better refer to `self.userInteractionEnabled` in the quoted `initWithFrame:` method.

Answer (score 1):

In Viewdidload  set

```
YourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    UITapGestureRecognizer * singleTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(openPhotoDetail:)];
   // Instead of self ,give your imageView to add gesture event  


      [YourImageView addGestureRecognizer: singleTap];
```

Comment: your callback function should be like - (void)openPhotoDetail:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

       NSLog(@"OpenPhotoDetail is called")
    }

Answer (score 0):

Click on the UIImageView, on storyboard,
Go to Attributes Inspector (The button that looks like a tuxedo, top right ,Second button).
Check the attribute "User Interaction Enabled"

Or if you want to do it by code,

in

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad {
    myImageView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     myImageView2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     myImageView3.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIImageView *MyImageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XYZ.png"]];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *TapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openPhotoDetail)];
    [MyImageview addGestureRecognizer:TapGesture];
    [MyImageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Can u use it like that